# Adding a blank row between dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a very basic load schedule for work.  We don't know ahead of time how many loads we'll be adding on a given day, but I'm trying to add a formula or script that will add a blank row between the sorted dates (i.e., all the loads for 11/20 will be listed, and then there will be a blank row).  It's purely aesthetic, I just don't want this thing to be miserable to look at.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of assumptions:
1) You use the first column for the date.
2) The first row is reserved for headers.
You could achieve this with the following script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var i = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    var baseRow = 0
    while(i > baseRow){
        if(values[i][0]!=values[i-1][0]){
            sheet.insertRowsAfter(i,1);
        }
        i--;
    }
}
```

If you have a different sheet, change the name of the Sheet.
If the chunk of rows are not starting from 1, change the baseRow value.